# Shared Preferences not working when using FCM backgroundHandler

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on this Flutter app and I have implemented Firebase Cloud Messaging. I added the following code to make sure I can use the Shared Preferences package. It seems to work, but the functionality does not work correctly.

### Extra configuration code

```dart
if (Platform.isAndroid) SharedPreferencesAndroid.registerWith();
  if (Platform.isIOS) SharedPreferencesIOS.registerWith();
```

### The backgroundhandler in action

```dart
Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  if (Platform.isAndroid) SharedPreferencesAndroid.registerWith();
  if (Platform.isIOS) SharedPreferencesIOS.registerWith();
  print("App is in background: Message received ");

  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final listOfTopics = prefs.getStringList('out_of_stock_topics') ?? [];

  String topic = 'default_topic';
  if (listOfTopics.contains(topic)) {
    listOfTopics.remove(topic);
    await prefs.setStringList('out_of_stock_topics', listOfTopics);
  }
}
```

The code above deletes the topic in the list. Then the list is set with prefs.setStringList. I checked, and the code goes into the if statement. It removes the item from the list. But something goes wrong in prefs.setStringList I suppose.

Because later I use the following code to check the items in the 'out_of_stock_topics' list.

### Code to check list of topics

```dart
 final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                final listOfTopics =
                    prefs.getStringList('out_of_stock_topics') ?? [];
                print(listOfTopics);
```

But the topic is not correctly deleted and is still there. I think there is something wrong in the backend of the backgroundhandler. I tested this feature with 2 buttons: "add topic" and "delete topic". And with those separate buttons it does delete the item from the 'out_of_stock_topics' list.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `listOfTopics` contains the string `default_topic` because that is what your code attempts to remove. After this `listOfTopics.remove(topic);` line, print `listOfTopics` to be sure the String is removed before saving.

Comment: Yes I am sure, I checked the listOfTopics and the length of list of topics as well.

Comment: @PeterO. Here is an image to clarify: https://imgur.com/a/rlCNNIF.
When I Hot restart the app (Shift + R), then the topic is removed. I don't know why this happens